# Custom Underline Using Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn, underline

In CSS, you can do custom underline with background images. This technique is explained here:

http://alistapart.com/article/customunderlines

Using this technique, I can do something like this:

[image]

With Prawn, the only underline I know of is using inline formatting:

```
text "<u>Ugly Underline</u>", size: 60, inline_format: TRUE
```

[image]

I subtle difference to some, but as a graphic designer this makes all the difference.

Does anyone know if any techniques that would allow me to do a custom underline using Prawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the :callback option for formatted_text_box.

```
class CustomUnderlineCallback

  def initialize(options)
    @document = options[:document]
  end

  def render_in_front(fragment)
    @document.stroke_color COLOR_WHITE
    @document.stroke_polygon fragment.bottom_left, fragment.bottom_right
    @document.stroke_color COLOR_BLACK
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table([["Does this work?"]] , :cell_style => {:borders => [:bottom]})
```

There are options to set `border-color` `width` etc.